# MariaDB server failing to stop in Docker container

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb

I am trying to create a Docker container for MariaDB server using Debian as the base image. My Dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM debian:buster

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install wget mariadb-server procps -y
COPY ./tools/init.sh /tmp/init.sh
RUN chmod +x /tmp/init.sh 
EXPOSE 3306
RUN sed -i 's/^bind-address\s*=.*/bind-address=0.0.0.0/' /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "/tmp/init.sh" ]
CMD [ "mysqld_safe" , "--verbose"]
```

for now I just want to get it to work so my `init.sh` script is simply:

```
service mysql start && service mysql stop
```

However, I'm getting a error of:

```
db             | Starting MariaDB database server: mysqld.
db             | ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
db             | Stopping MariaDB database server: mysqld failed!
db exited with code 1
db             | Starting MariaDB database server: mysqld.
db             | ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
db             | Stopping MariaDB database server: mysqld failed!
db exited with code 1
db             | Starting MariaDB database server: mysqld.
db             | ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
db             | Stopping MariaDB database server: mysqld failed!
db exited with code 1
db             | Starting MariaDB database server: mysqld.
db             | ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
db             | Stopping MariaDB database server: mysqld failed!
db exited with code 1
db             | Starting MariaDB database server: mysqld.
db             | ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
db             | Stopping MariaDB database server: mysqld failed!
db exited with code 1
```

it seems that the database is started successfully while the second line suggests that I am trying to use the root user without a password, but I read that by default, the root password is blank, and I'm not setting it or using MySQL client anywhere, so I frankly have no idea where that is coming from. The third line shows that the MariaDB server is failing to stop, which I also have no idea why.

### what i have tried to troubleshoot the problem:

1. I manually `docker run --rm -it --name testing_db debian` and run all the instructions from dockerfile inside the container, everything worked fine and was able to start and stop the database server ??
2. to troubleshoot the problem of access denied I read somewhere to try to reset the root password, so i tried doing so in a RUN instruction in the Dockerfile as
   `RUN service mysql start &&  mysql -u root -e  "ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"`
   however, that didn't solve the issue.

What are your thoughts in this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this will work if you delete the `ENTRYPOINT` line and the `init.sh` script.

A Docker container only runs one command.  That command is [constructed](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact) by passing the `CMD` as arguments to the `ENTRYPOINT`.  When the `ENTRYPOINT` process exits, the container exits too.

In your case the `init.sh` just runs two `service` commands and exits.  `service` broadly doesn't work in Docker, though.  One of the ways it can fail is that the `service` command launches the service in the background, so if your container's main process is just to run `service mysql start`, when that command completes the container exits too.

The right answer here is to not use `service` but rather to just run the main container process in the foreground.  You already have that as your `CMD`, though, you're just not running it.  This is where, if you delete the `ENTRYPOINT`, then `CMD` alone will be the main container process.

---

If you do need to keep the `ENTRYPOINT`, then you need to make sure it runs the `CMD` when it's done with its initial setup.  The standard way to do this is to end the script with `exec "$@"`

```bash
#!/bin/sh
# init.sh

# ... do startup-time setup ...

# run the main CMD
exec "$@"
```

This approach can be useful for setting environment variables, copying files around, rendering injected templated configuration files, and some other simple startup-time tasks.

Getting this to actually initialize a database is tricky.  The standard `mariadb` image has an involved entrypoint script that starts a database as a background process (without using `service`) and without a network listener, then running the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` scripts, then killing the local-only database and starting the real one.